# apache2 disable redirect to https

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, https

My subdomain return me to https when I logout from my drupal website

I have tried to disable ssl and restart apache2 but not working
I have tried also to modify .htaccess file but always KO

and this only happened with this subdomain , All others domains works fine
my subdomain conf file

```sh
<VirtualHost sub.domain.fr:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mydomain.fr
        DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/mydomain/public_html/app2.mydomain.fr
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <Directory "/home/ubuntu/mydomain/public_html/app2.mydomain.fr">
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

apache2.conf file

```sh
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On


MaxKeepAliveRequests 100


KeepAliveTimeout 5


User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}


HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log


LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf


<Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>



AccessFileName .htaccess


<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent


IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

Include sites-enabled/
```

ports.conf file

```sh
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80
Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, change your vhost config to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.fr
```

then make sure the redirect doesn't happen just because of your browser cache: always use and anonymous window or, even better, simulate the navigation using curl so you don't use any kind of cached response.